# I can't configure tensorflow to work with the GPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

I'm using a lenovo l340 15 irh laptop, it has a discrete nvidia 1650 graphics card.
OS: Windows
Python version: 3.9.13
IDE: Visual Studio Code

I have already installed CUDA, cuDNN, but the code

```
len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))>0
```

continues to return False.

To investigate the problem, I wrote `nvidia-sli` on the windows command line and got the following result:
[nvidia-smi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUt10.png)

Then I wrote `nvidia-smi --query-gpu=compute_cap --format=csv` and got this:
[nvidia-smi --query-gpu=compute_cap --format=csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8bIX.png)

Then I discovered which versions I should use. My tensorflow version is 2.14.0 so last version of CUDA did not fit this tensorflow. I uninstalled it and installed CUDA v11.8 but it didn't help.

Then I installed cuDNN which supporting work with CUDA v11.x but it didn't help either.

I also added to system variable "Path" actual paths for cuDNN v11.x and v12.x:
[Path variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUrvH.png)

Now I'm stuck and I can't figure out what to do next. Can you help me?

Comment: Did you install tensorflow cuda version? `# For GPU users
pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]`

Comment: Before your comment, no, now I have done it, but in tensorflow cuda version tensorflow version = 2.13.1, and I had 2.14. I understand that the older version of tensorflow will not be activated while there is a new one, so I will try now to completely remove this package and re-download tensorflow cuda version. I'll write here as soon as I do it!

Comment: made it, nothing's changed

Answer (score 0):

Kindy install the required Hardware and Software requirements by this using this link Software and Hardware . and follow the step by step instructions.

Once you have installed all the required software and hardware requirements please follow below steps.

> System requirements:

Windows 10 19044 or higher (64-bit). This corresponds to Windows 10 version 21H2, the November 2021 update.

> GPU setup :

Install the NVIDIA GPU driver if you have not. You can use the following command to verify it is installed.

```
nvidia-smi
```

> Install TensorFlow :

TensorFlow requires a recent version of pip, so upgrade your pip installation to be sure you're running the latest version.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Then, install TensorFlow with pip.

```
 # For GPU users
 pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
```

> Verify the installation:

Verify the GPU setup:

`python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"`

If a list of GPU devices is returned, you've installed TensorFlow successfully.

Follow the above steps to install the tensorflow-gpu.